# Which of these two is the proper way to implement a header?

Tags: c++, function, header

Should you include #include the header of your function declaration in the source file where you define the function?

I've tried both and it seems to work either way. I was wondering if either way is preferred or if one might cause an error in a different compiler

```
//header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
int squareVal (int);
#endif

//squareVal.cpp
//should I #include "header.h" here as well? 
int squareVal (int val){
return (val*val);
}

//main.cpp
#include"header.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
cout << squareVal(2) << endl;
}
```

Both ways seem to work. From my testing and research it sounds like the linker is able to find squareVal.cpp regardless of including the header in that file or not.

Comment: In this minimal example, it's not technically necessary to include `header.h` in `squareVal.cpp`. But usually, a header declares more than just one function - it may define types, or enums, or several functions that may need to call each other. In general, the implementation file does need declarations from the header.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Your function declaration is missing a variable name.  Common coding guidelines recommend using variable names in function declarations (especially when there are multiple parameters with the same type).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Answer down below in the answer section come on mate you know the drill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it makes a difference, depends on the contents of the header.

In this specific case, because a function definition does not require a previous function declaration, the `#include` in `squareVal.cpp` is not (and never will be) necessary.

However, imagine if the header contained more than the function declaration? What if it defined some types needed by the function? What if it defined some constants needed by the function definition? Then you'd need an `#include`.

It is considered good practice to `#include` regardless, because then you do not need to think about this, and doing so is effectively free.

Comment: I definitely see how that could be problematic , thank you! @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 1):

Use the `#include` directive. Put it at the top, in front of any other `#include` directives. That way, if there's a mistake in the header, the compiler will be more likely to find it. In particular, if you declare the function differently from the way you define it, the compiler will notice. If you don't pull in the header, translation units that use that header will see a different signature from the one that's been defined, and you'll get errors when you try to link. It's much easier when you see the problem early.

Comment: Thank you, each of these answers helped me to understand. @PeteBecker

Answer (score 0):

The compiler simply puts the WHOLE code from the header right where you insert the `#include "header.h"`. So in this example, the declaration is before the definition of the function and it does nothing bad.